# Can't create database with Entity Framework code-first

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I try to create a database in SQL Server with Entity Framework code-first in a Windows form application. The program runs with no error, but I can't see any database in my SQL Server. Why?

I created 2 classes

```
public class Country :System.Object
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Country()
    {

    }

    public Country(int id, string name)
    {
            this.Id = id;
            this.Name = name;
    }
}

class DataBaseContext : System.Data.Entity.DbContext
{
    public DataBaseContext()
        : base("connectionStringName")
    {

    }

    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Country> countries { get; set; }
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Models.DataBaseContext ODB = null;

        try
        {
            ODB = new Models.DataBaseContext();
            Models.Country OCountries = new Models.Country();
            OCountries.Id = 1;
            OCountries.Name="AA";
            ODB.countries.Add(OCountries);
            ODB.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally   
        {
            if (ODB != null)
            {
                 ODB.Dispose();
                 ODB = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and `app.config` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<configSections>

<section name="entityFramework"             type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
</configSections>
<startup>
 <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
</startup>
<entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
 <parameters>
 <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
 </parameters>
  </defaultConnectionFactory>
  <providers>
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
  <providers>

 </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Do you get any exceptions when you run the code?

Answer (score 1):

Base on your connection string the database will be created in localdb.

You can open Sql Server Management Studio and change "Server name" to `(localdb)\mssqllocaldb` and "Authentication" to "Windows Authentication" and login to your local db instance installed on your system. There you can find the database created by Entity Framework.

Also keep in mind that .NET has unified object model which means you don't need to derived a class from it so change `public class Country :System.Object` to `public class Country`

Comment: thanks doctor , I try But  any Database  dosen't create in sql. I entered with (localDB)\v11.0 too but i gave same result

Comment: Do you get any exception?